# Find $ \ 3 \ $ vectors having same orthogonal projection on $ \vec a=(1,2) \ $.

Tags: vectors, projective-geometry

Find  $ \ 3 \ $ vectors   having same orthogonal projection on $ \vec a=(1,2) \ $.

**Answer:**

Suppose I take a vector $ \vec b=(2,1) \ $ . Then the orthogonal projection is

$ (|\vec b| \cos \theta ) \frac{\vec a}{|\vec a |} \ $

But how to find more two vectors having same orthogonal projection on $ \vec a \ $ as $ \vec b \ $ .

Is one of them $ -\vec b \ $ ?

Please help me .

Comment: Hint: there’s an entire line for which this projection is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes one of them is $-b$, for finding other vectors, just assume $c=(a,x) \ a\  is \ a \ constant$. Use the formula that you have written to find $x$ so that $c$ also have the same projection.

Comment: Tell him something about a vector orthogonal to (1,2) e.g. (-2,1) and how any vector (1,2)+a(-2,1) will have the same orthogonal projection because it eliminates the orthogonal components

Comment: because i suck at explainig

Comment: what does it mean $ c=(a,x) \ $ ?